# How to validate a string contains at least 6 distinct digits using regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to get a Regex that checks to make sure that a supplied integer is 9 digits long and shall contain at least 6 non-repetitive digits

Example:

> 123456123 ------> Matches (6 different digits)
>   123243521 ------> Does not match (5 different digits)

Comment: You would be better off doing it without a regex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is much easier to do without a regex:

```
var str = "1234567890";
var isOk = str.Length >= 9
    && str.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9')
    && str.Distinct().Count() >= 6;
```